# nagios's priority for host vs service the other way around

Tags: nagios

I'm just curios, let's say i made a definition for a host and i specified it to check/notify at certain time 10-18 yet in service i said 24/7, who's taking priority? would i get alerts 24/7 or would it fall under host's rules and it'd be 10-18?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you would get a notification for the service. However, you might not get the service notification if the service is down as a result of the host being down. Nagios configs can be complicated, I always recommend testing.

Comment: +1 for recommending testing. Every time I think I understand part of it testing proves me wrong. :(

Comment: John Gardeniers: Ya, Nagios config can be tricky and have edge cases, check out this edge case I ran into: http://ideas.nagios.org/a/dtd/19130-3955

Answer (score 0):

Note that a service failure can trigger a host check.  So if it's outside of the host check time period, but the service check fails, I believe it will specifically request a host check.  If the host is down and you are outside of the notify time period, I believe it will swallow your alert.  This may or may not be what you intend.

However, it seems odd that you would check the service 24/7 but the host it runs on only 8/7.

As with all things nagios, make sure you test both service and host failures in the different time periods to ensure it is acting as you expect.